# How to fix path issues resulted from union operation?

Tags: blender, inkscape

The path looks ok when I edit it in **Inkscape**, but when imported to **Blender** it's deformed and I have no clue how to fix it. I have a suspicion that the problem has to do with union operation I used in Inkscape to join two paths. Here are two images (top inkscape, bottom blender).
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using "Simplify" command on the path.